# Is the value of these two same double Integrals of different upper limit of y equal when i shift to polar coordinates and use Jacobian?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, lebesgue-integral, indefinite-integrals

In a example question its given that $$\int\int(x^2+y^2)dydx$$ where x=0 to $\sqrt{1-y^2}$ and y=0 to 1. In an exercise question same question is given but the only difference is that y=0 to 1/2. But after shifting to polar coordinates, with r=0 to 1 and $\theta$=0 to pi/2 and Taking Jacobian it seems that answer of both are same and matching with the bookish answer given. Is it really so ? Image has been added for convenience [image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to MSE! Please review the [mathjax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Images cannot be read by screenreaders.

Comment: In case with $y_{max}=1/2$, the upper limit of $r$ depends on $\theta$ when $\theta > \pi/6$, to find it out, you should plot the integration area in $xy$-plane.

Comment: @Ivan Kaznacheyeu Ok. Thanks i got it now. I see my question has been downvoted by someone. Please help me by upvoting the question. Typing Mathjax takes too much time and felt it was easier to use imagem that's why i use image.

Comment: Please use mathjax as it is the standard expected here

Answer (score 2):

At the intersection of $y = r \sin\theta = \frac{1}{2}$ and circle with $r = 1$,

$\sin\theta = \frac{1}{2} \implies \theta = \frac{\pi}{6}$

a) So for $0 \leq \theta \leq \frac{\pi}{6}$, $0 \leq r \leq 1$

b) For $\frac{\pi}{6} \leq \theta \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$, the upper bound of $r$ is defined by the line $y = \frac{1}{2}$ and not the circle.

$y \leq \frac{1}{2} \implies r \sin\theta \leq \frac{1}{2}$

So you have, $0 \leq r \leq \frac{\csc \theta}{2}$

So you need to split the integral into two. Draw a diagram of the region to understand it better.

Comment: Hello Maths Lover i understood the thing clearly now. Thank you so much. can you please upvote my question. ? Someone has downvoted my question . I promise to upvote and accept your answer as best if you could upvote my question.

Comment: @SwarnavaChandraBose I would not get into an arrangement that I upvote your question expecting in return that you upvote my answer. I would rather say that you should try and understand why you got downvoted. We all get downvoted sometimes without a clear reason but in this case I think it is to do with you not using mathjax. We do not encourage screenshots on the site as it cannot be searched. Also readability depends on one's handwriting. You showed your effort in solving which is good and if you start using mathjax, you will see much better appreciation from community for your question.

Comment: That was a very careful reply @MathLover